# Limit distinct values only if a subelement exists

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nosql, mongodb-query

I have searched here but could not find an clear answer to the following question.  In the sample collection `mycollection` below, how would one select distinct `vin` numbers **only** in Objects where the `status` field exists and the `status` is `UNLOCKED` ?

I have tried

```
db.getCollection('mycollection').distinct("vin",  {$and: [{"decoded_payload.status": {$exists: true}}, {"decoded_payload.status":"UNLOCKED"}]})
```

but this query hangs indefinitely

Due to the large size of the database and the lengthy delay of such a query, I would like to limit the output to check if it runs at all but it seems `limit()` is not an option with `.distinct()`

In MongoDB, how would one select the distinct `vin` in the data below, set the limit = 1 and only select based on the `status` condition (`status` exists and is equal to "UNLOCKED")?

Would `aggregate()` be the right choice? How does one use the above conditions with `aggregate()` and `limit()` ?

The output in this case would be **34567**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("1"),
    "vin" : "12345",
    "class_name" : "foo",
    "decoded_payload" : {
        "timestamp" : 1547329250,
        "status" : "LOCKED"
    }
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("2"),
    "vin" : "23456",
    "class_name" : "foo",
    "decoded_payload" : {
        "timestamp" : 1547329260,
        "status" : "LOCKED"
    }
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("3"),
    "vin" : "34567",
    "class_name" : "bar",
    "decoded_payload" : {
        "timestamp" : 1547329270,
        "status" : "UNLOCKED",
        "reservation_id" : "71"

    }
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("4"),
    "vin" : "45678",
    "class_name" : "baz",
    "decoded_payload" : {
        "timestamp" : 1547329280,
        "reservation_id" : "71"

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this aggregation Query to filter data and return distinct **"vin"**

```
db.mycollection.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            $and: [{
                    "decoded_payload.status": { $exists: true }
                   }, {
                    "decoded_payload.status": "UNLOCKED"
            }]
        }
    },
    { $limit : 5 }, // You can use this stage after group too
    {
        $group: { _id: "$vin" }
    }
])
```

Use limit stage before and after **$group** stage as per requirement